# Elasticsearch "Query string" query on Geo?

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, gremlin, titan

I'm trying to do a query on Elasticsearch using the query string interface on a Geolocation. Specifically, I am trying to return all documents within a circle (point with radius). This is clearly possible using the full query DSL based on JSON. However, I can't find the syntax for the same search using query strings in the docs here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

Does this mean geo queries are not supported by query string queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not supported as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @dadnoonet. Do you know of any more evidence of this other than the docs link I posted?